# Load kubeflow pipeline yaml

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm using **kfp V1** and I'm looking for a "native" way to load a kubeflow pipeline yaml into memory (ideally in python) and manipulate it.

For example, I can load a component yaml into memory and manipulate it:

```py
kfp.components.load_component_from_file("component.yaml")
# manipulate the component
```

In kfp **V2** it's possible using the exact same method.

I've been trying to use the same method `load_component_from_file` which fails for pipelines and was searching for similar `load_pipeline_from_file` but it seems it does not exist.

Comment: What exactly is happening? I tried it like so: 
```import kfp
kfp.components.load_component_from_file("pipeline.yaml")
```
Output: `<kfp.dsl.yaml_component.YamlComponent at 0x7f89c3011d90>`
Isn't that what you want?